# Typescirpt : XMLHttpRequest is not defined in .ts file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

i have a .ts file with this code:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

when i run the grunt task to build the ts files with typescript, there are no errors.
When i try to instance the class and call the function with this line appear this error:

> ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
>       at HttpRequester.send (C:**\asset-player\src\assetlib\HttpRequester.js:9:25)
>       at AssetFinder.Asset.req (C:**\asset-player\src\assetlib\Asset.js:41:21)
>       at Object. (C:**\asset-player\index.js:21:20)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:429:10)
>       at startup (node.js:139:18)
>       at node.js:999:3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript gives, "Could not find a declaration file for module 'xmlhttprequest'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51603854/typescript-gives-could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to reference a file which (eventually) contains `XMLHttpRequest` declaration.

That declaration is eventually here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts

You may want to double-check your typescript configuration:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript

Comment: I downloaded the file lib.webworker.d.ts and included it in my project then i referenced it, in the file that need XMLHttpRequest, in this way

/// <reference path="lib.webworker.d.ts" />
I noticed that this file reference lib.core.d.ts, so i included also this file. Unfortunally the grunt task of typescript is not able to compile the files and it report a very long list of errors.

Likely i am referencing the file in a wrong way. Can you help me?

Comment: Did you follow the installation guide at: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript ?

Comment: I list the step that i have done:
npm install -g typescript
npm install -g typescript@next
npm install -g jake
And then, in the project directory:
jake LKG

So? What is the next step?

Comment: Now i found lib.webworker in my local node_modules folder. Then i referenced it:
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts" />

How can i use XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include `"lib": ["dom"]` in the `compilerOptions` of the `tsconfig.json`

(in my case I needed `"lib": ["es6", "dom"]`)