# Typescript gives, "Could not find a declaration file for module 'xmlhttprequest'."

Tags: node.js, typescript, xmlhttprequest

Using,

```
import { XMLHttpRequest } from 'xmlhttprequest';
```

On Node I get the following error when I compile with `tsc`

> index.ts|4 col 32 error| 7016[QF available]: Could not find a declaration file for module '`xmlhttprequest`'. '`<project>/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js`' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try `npm install @types/xmlhttprequest` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '`xmlhttprequest`';`

However, that package doesn't seem to be there,

```
npm install @types/xmlhttprequest
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @types/xmlhttprequest@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ecarroll/.npm/_logs/2018-07-31T00_19_20_299Z-debug.log
```

Is there a way anything that packages this type?

Answer (score 1):

That means that the library does not contain type definitions and nobody from the DefinitelyTyped project wrote them. So you can't have the compiler do any typechecking. You can still use the library either

```
import * as xhr from 'xmlhttprequest'
```

Or, depending on version of your compiler

```
const xhr = require('xmlhttprequest')
```

Comment: This prints the same thing, ./lib/UNGEGN.ts|3 col 22 error| 7016[QF available]: Could not find a declaration file for module 'xmlhttprequest'. '/home/ecarroll/code/toponym-esque/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try `npm install @types/xmlhttprequest` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'xmlhttprequest';`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do `npm install @types/xmlhttprequest --save` in your command line.

If it gives you error, then it means that xmlhttprequest library does not support TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

The types for this library are now [on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/xmlhttprequest), so you can run either `npm install --save-dev @types/xmlhttprequest` or `yarn add --dev @types/xmlhttprequest` to install them.